# Why does 1000BASE-T use CAT5?

Tags: ethernet, cables

I read in some articles that CAT5 is used in 1000BASE-T and supports up to 100 Mbps, however, 1000BASE-T operates at 1000 Mbps. Does using CAT5e make more sense?

Comment: It's simple. Cat 5 is certified for 100Mbps. Cat 5e is certified for 1000Mbps. If you want 1000Mbps, use Cat 5e. That said, I dont't think you will be able to buy Cat 5 anymore and Cat 5e has completely replaced it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Summary

IEEE 802.3ab / 1000BASE-T was explicitly designed to provide 1000Mbps over 100 meters of Category 5 cabling, which had a large installed base at the time.

However, after 802.3ab was ratified (in Jun 1999), they found that the Category 5 specifications were not tight enough to guarantee this under all circumstances. To rectify this, in 2000 a revision to the cabling specification called Category 5e was introduced in ANSI/TIA/EIA-568-A-5 to tighten those guarantees.

Despite not being guaranteed, most existing Category 5 cables already met the required performance, and 1000BASE-T should work fine over it. When you have the choice, you should prefer Category 5e over Category 5. Category 5 hasn't been available new for almost two decades anyway.

### Sources

[This Fluke article](https://www.flukenetworks.com/knowledge-base/application-or-standards-articles-copper/1000base-t-over-category-5) has a lot of useful details. Some choice quotes:

> This article is intended to clarify the physical layer requirements for Gigabit Ethernet (1000BASE-T) over balanced twisted pair cabling. The IEEE802.3ab standard for Gigabit Ethernet over balance twisted pair cabling was approved in June 28, 1999. This is important to note, since category 5e was not approved until January 2000 as ANSI/TIA/EIA-568-A-5. This would suggest that Gigabit Ethernet may not require category 5e performance. (You should install category 5e as a minimum today)

...

> For example, the Intel 82544EI and 82544GC Gigabit Ethernet Controllers were specifically designed to run over the installed base of category 5.
>
> BUT, vendors such as Intel required further information that was not initially available. To make it work, the IEEE needed to split the 1000 Mb/s into four paths, one for each of the four pairs. What caused the headache was that each pair would transmit and received at the same time full duplex. This meant that some new important test parameters had to be defined. Problem was that these were unknown for the installed base of category 5.

...

> The IEEE turned to the TIA (Telecommunications Industry Association) and its members for help. The TIA was asked to come up with a set of limit lines for these missing parameters that would represent the majority of the installed base of category 5 cabling (>85 %). The IEEE would then work around these figures.

...

> ... an addendum to the existing ANSI/TIA/EIA-568-A was required. This came in the form of addendum 5 and the introduction of category 5e. Cabling components had improved since the introduction of category 5 in 1995.

[The IEEE 802.3ab page](https://standards.ieee.org/ieee/802.3ab/1086/) is a bit less explicit, but its title clearly says Category 5:

> **Physical Layer Parameters and Specifications for 1000 Mb/s Operation over 4 pair of Category 5 Balanced Copper Cabling, Type 1000BASE-T**

[These IEEE slides from Colin Mick et al](https://grouper.ieee.org/groups/802/3/tutorial/march98/mick_170398.pdf) explicitly mention targeting the existing Category 5 installed base:

> Page 5, Target Market
>
> - 70% of installed UTP is CAT 5

> Page 7, Objectives
>
> - Support operation over 100 meters of Category 5 balanced cabling

### Back to the question

> Why does 1000BASE-T use CAT5?

Because that's what was in widespread use when 1000BASE-T was designed.

> I read in some articles that CAT5 is used in 1000BASE-T and supports up to 100 Mbps, however, 1000BASE-T operates at 1000 Mbps.

Those articles would be wrong then; 1000BASE-T is 1000Mbps, period. Network controllers *may* fall back to 100BASE-TX if a 1000BASE-T link can't be established though, perhaps that's what they meant. However, it's likely 1000BASE-T will just work over a Category 5 installation.

> Does using CAT5e make more sense?

Absolutely, because only Category 5e is *guaranteed* to meet the required specifications. Category 5 isn't, quite.

That being said:

- 1000BASE-T was introduced when only Category 5 was available
- Category 5e specifications are such that at least 85% of existing Category 5 cabling qualified
- With runs significantly shorter than 100 meters, even Category 5 cables that don't qualify may very well be able to support 1000BASE-T. I've seen people run 1000BASE-T over short-ish runs of Category 3, and that seemed to work...

So yeah, if you have the choice, absolutely prefer 5e, or better. But if you have an existing Category 5 installation, 1000BASE-T is likely to work fine on that.